# How to swap HC-05 bluetooth module out of COMMAND mode and into DATA mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, hc-05

I'm trying (and successfully) connecting an android device to an HC-05 bluetooth module via the bluetooth adapter library in android studio. The issue is that we cannot send commands to the module because when we connect to it the module automatically switches to command mode (even though the enable pin isn't set) and we can only send commands to it in data mode. We have tried sending the module the command "AT+RESET" but this doesn't work and we believe it has something to do with pin 34 being set. Anything at all about the subject would be helpful.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: @fartem Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and update your answer.